# How do I find the Basis of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a basis of the following vector space: $ V = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1+x_2+x_3=0 \}$

In order to find it I saw that you could do the following:

$(x_1, x_2, x_3)  = (-x_2, x_2, 0) + (-x_3, 0, x_3) = x_2(-1, 1, 0) + x_3 (-1, 0, 1)$

I understand the computations of course but why does that represent a basis of V, and what exactly is the basis?

Comment: Give l.i. choices to free variables...

Comment: for example $x_{1}=1,x_{2}=0,x_{3}=-1,$ then $x_{1}=0,x_{2}=1,x_{3}=-1$ if you consider $x_{1},x_{2}$ as free..

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

You got two independent vectors $(-1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$ and they generate any vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.

Comment: Yes of course! thank you, I needed to refresh my memory